# JAVA_HOME variable is not recognized in Win 7 Pro 32 bit

Tags: java-home

I have set JAVA_HOME system variable to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30** and added **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** to Path variable.

When I check list of variables using new session of cmd I cannot see JAVA_HOME variable on the list at all, however Path variable contains record **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin**.

When I want to run mvn I get:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation
```

I double checked configuration, restarted the machine and the problem persists.

Can you please advise? It looks like the variables are set, but JAVA_HOME does not make it to the list of variables, however value which derives from it makes it to the Path variable

Comment: How/where did you set JAVA_HOME? If you set it in a cmd prompt it will disappear as soon as you exit the cmd prompt.

Comment: I set it as system variable using advanced system properties. I have also added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to Path system variable. When I check in new cmd prompt for system variables JAVA_HOME is not displayed at all, while %JAVA_HOME%\bin is resolved to correct value.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Plus, when I check the environment variables, %JAVA_HOME%\bin doesn't show as a value in the Path variable. please help!